# Ember {{each}} helper not showing complete list

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My template:

```
{{#each lesson_types}}
    {{name}}: ${{price}}
{{/each}}
{{#view App.EnterFormView action="pushType"}}
    {{input value=currentName placeholder="Lesson Name"}} {{input value=currentPrice placeholder="Lesson Price"}}
{{/view}}
<button {{action "saveTypes"}}>Save</button>
```

The problem is with that `{{each}}` block, which only renders it's *first* entry.

The `pushType` method:

```
pushType: function() {
    console.log(this.get('lesson_types'));
    if (!this.get('lesson_types')) this.set('lesson_types', []);

    this.get('lesson_types').push(Ember.Object.create({name: this.get('currentName'), price: this.get('currentPrice')}));
    console.log(this.get('lesson_types'));

    this.setProperties({currentName: '', currentPrice: 0});
}
```

and the `EnterFormView` simply triggers it's method on its parent's controller if the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed while it has focus.

Everything works great, until I enter things in that form. If I typed "Full" and "30" and then "Half" and "15" into those inputs, only the "Full" "30" would show up in the each, even though the console outputs of `pushType` show this:

```
undefined
[Class, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function, getEach: function…]

[Class, _super: undefined, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…]    
[Class, Class, _super: undefined, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…]
```

so you can see the array *is growing properly*, the `{{each}}` just isn't showing all the entries.

It is worth pointing out that `lesson_types` **is a property of the model**.

**Update**

Here's a pastebin of the expanded output http://pastebin.com/UrEutPxZ
which shows strangely that the second object is different than the first. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using pushObject instead of push

Push won't notify ember that the array has changed